# ResponseEntity - How to handle status codes that are different from 200 ok?

Tags: java, spring, rest, error-handling

I am working on a REST API client and I have one Class responsible for all request directives since for that I am going to be using the exact same provider. I am currently being able to send, receive and process the responses as long as they are 200 OKs.
However, as soon as I start to receive anything different from it, I get errors and my program stops running.

```
    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-02-09 15:17:09.359 ERROR 24504 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.infobipcommunity.InfobipApisApplication.main(InfobipApisApplication.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{
    "requestError": {
        "serviceException": {
            "messageId": "BAD_REQUEST",
            "text": "[from : may not be null, to : size must be between 1 and 2147483647]"
        }
    }
}]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:101) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:186) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:818) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:710) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:601) ~[spring-web-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.infobipcommunity.configuration.Request.requestExecutor(Request.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.infobipcommunity.controller.RequestManagerSms.getDeliveryReport(RequestManagerSms.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.infobipcommunity.InfobipApisApplication.run(InfobipApisApplication.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:804) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

As per evidence you can see I am getting the response body and I am being able to print it, unfortunately I cannot pass it on to the next class.

This is the method I am using to fetch data:

```
public AdvanceSmsDlrResponse getDeliveryReport() {

        AdvanceSmsDlrResponse dlrResponse = new AdvanceSmsDlrResponse();
        try {
            dlrResponse = objectMapper.readValue((String) requestExecutor(null, "/sms/1/reports", HttpMethod.GET,
                    "com.infobipcommunity.models.responses.sms.getDeliveryReport.AdvanceSmsDlrResponse"), AdvanceSmsDlrResponse.class);
            return null;
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new AdvanceSmsDlrResponse();
        }
    }
```

The generic method that is being called in the previous snippet:

```
public Object requestExecutor(Object requestBody, String requestPath, HttpMethod httpMethod, String className) {

    entity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBody, httpHeaders);
        response = requestRestTemplate.exchange(getUrlhost() + requestPath, httpMethod, entity, className.getClass());
        LOGGER.info("\n" + response.toString());
        return response.getBody();

}
```

So my question is, how is this meant to be handled?

Additionally, I wanted to ask if there is a way I can make sure that the object using the method *getDeliveryReport* is able to handle the positive and negative results (AdvanceSmsDlrResponse.class or ApiException.class)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch `RestClientResponseException` and get the result using `getResponseBodyAsString()` from the exception. Then you can use jackson to map it to an object.

This is how I handled it, maybe there are other ways.

Regarding the last question, I guess you will need to add another field in the response object in order to be able to pass the JSON from the exception. Another way would be to rethrow the exception using another expcetion and catch later or not rethrow it at all and catch it later.

Comment: tzortzik, thanks for the information... I did it like this: